# CodeIgniter - force_download() no output

Tags: php, codeigniter, download

Fast to explain, but I can't get it to work:

In this simple code, the function force_download simply doesn't make any output.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents("modulos/".$filename); // Read the file's contents
force_download($filename, $data);
echo $data."/".$filename;
```

Here I just get a white screen, but the file content is show (well you know, the strange codified content :)
I think it is simple enough, I just want the file downloaded with no other effect, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the force_download function? If you expect us to help, you have to show us all parts of the problem. Otherwise we have to ask you for it, and that makes us less willing to help.

Comment: I could Treeface, but it is a Codeigniter System helper, not suposed to be failing, the fuction itself has be long term tested. Anyway, i have solved the problem, it was a misconfiguration of my localhost, who was not undertstanding the headers the function wrotes.

Answer (score 5):

This will work with you

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$path = file_get_contents(base_url()."modulos/".$filename); // get file name
$name = "sample_file.pdf"; // new name for your file
force_download($name, $path); // start download`
```

Comment: i was missing to include helper

Comment: thank you brother. your awesome. you save me a lot of time and stress..

Answer (score 4):

Just a note to anyone else who may be having this problem: Make sure you have a file extension on the filename you supply for the first argument to `force_download()`.

CodeIgniter uses this to set the MIME type, and it doesn't seem to work without.

Answer (score 0):

Remove that `echo $data."/".$filename;` It should be like this

```
$this->load->helper('download');
$data = file_get_contents("modulos/".$filename); // Read the file's contents
force_download($filename, $data);
```

Comment: I _think_ the echo is just in there for debugging purposes? Don't see why else anybody would put that there ;)

Comment: yes Tilman, the echo is there just for testing i was getting file contents properly.

Comment: force_download is working fine in pc but not working in android device

Answer (score 0):

You should not call function after force_download(), Just remove the last line.

Answer (score -1):

remove base_`url()` and do like this

```
$path= file_get_contents('./uploads/abc.jpg);
```

Comment: $fileContents = file_get_contents('./uploads/abc.jpg);