# Force Download in Codeigniter doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to download a file using `force_download` in codeigniter.

I create an AJAX call like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    , url: '<?php echo base_url('downloadPayroll'); ?>'
    , data: { filename: filename }
});
```

And here is my controller

```
public function downloadPayroll() {
    $filename = $this->input->post('filename');
    $fileContents = file_get_contents(base_url('assets/uploads/'. $filename));

    force_download($filePath, $fileContents);
}
```

I know I have the correct path and filename but it doesn't download anything.

What am I doing wrong because the documentation for [Download Helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/download_helper.html) is very limited.

Comment: your file name must be with extension.

Comment: Enable all warnings, output name and make sure this file exist and not empty. Use some utility to monitor file access in your OS.

Comment: This solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30261836/codeigniters-force-download-problems

Comment: You can't use AJAX for download a file.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code. You are passing wrong variable name for `force_download`

```
$filename = $this->input->post('filename');
$fileContents = file_get_contents(base_url('assets/uploads/'. $filename)); 
$file='test.pdf';
force_download($file, $fileContents);
```

Comment: Please make sure you specify the file format  for the first argument force_download .

Answer (score 0):

Just a note to anyone else who may be having this problem: Make sure you have a file extension on the filename you supply for the first argument to `force_download()`.

CodeIgniter uses this to set the MIME type, and it doesn't seem to work without.

for more [CodeIgniter - force_download() problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985592/codeigniter-force-download-problem).

```
$name = 'myfile.txt';//file extension is required
force_download($name, NULL);//if you dont want to send data set NULL
```

And Don't forget to load `download` helper first.

```
$this->load->helper('download');
```

Comment: I have included the download helper in my autoload. Also, I already tried hardcoding my filename into the `force_download` function but I still didn't get any response from the server.

Comment: enable `file_get_contents` on server.

Comment: for more see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256060/enabling-file-get-contents-on-a-shared-server

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to download a file via an ajax request like that - try this instead

your JS File

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST'
    , url: '<?php echo base_url('downloadPayroll'); ?>'
    , data: { filename: filename },

    success: function(strUrl)
    {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.style = "display: none";
        link.href = strUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        setTimeout(function () {
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }, 5000);   
    }
});
```

Your Controller:

```
public function downloadPayroll() 
{
    $filename = $this->input->post('filename');
    echo base_url('assets/uploads/'. $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the helper

```
public function downloadPayroll() {
$filename = $this->input->post('filename');
$fileContents = file_get_contents(base_url('assets/uploads/'. $filename));

$this->load->helper( 'download' );

force_download($filePath, $fileContents);
```

}